# Intercepting Adobe Reader "Print to File" dialog box

Tags: vb.net, pdf, printing, dialog, .net-3.5

I am currently attempting to print a PDF to a file using a printer set up with a file port.  This works however it brings up the an Adobe Reader dialog box asking for a file path.  This is something I want to avoid and want to enter the file path myself and press the OK button through code so there is no user interaction for the print operation whatsoever.  I have been experimenting with some code I found but have had little success.  I was hoping someone could have a look and see where I am going wrong with my code or other an alternative method to try:

I have used the following API functions:

```
    Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
        (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
         ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

    Public Declare Function SendDlgItemMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendDlgItemMessageA" _
        (ByVal hDlg As Long, _
         ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, _
         ByVal Msg As Long, _
         ByVal wParam As Long, _
         ByVal lParam As String) As Long

    Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
        (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
         ByVal wMsg As Long, _
         ByVal wParam As Long, _
         ByRef lParam As Long) As Long

    Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
        (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
         ByVal wMsg As Long, _
         ByVal wParam As Long, _
         ByRef lParam As String) As Long

    Public Declare Function GetDlgItem Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal hDlg As Long, _
         ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long) As Long

    Public Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
        (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, _
         ByVal hWnd2 As Long, _
         ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
         ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

    Public Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
    Public Const WM_SHOWWINDOW = &H18
    Public Const WM_LBUTTONUP = &H202
    Public Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN = &H201
    Public Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
    Public Const IDOK = 1
```

The main operation for finding and filling the window is held within a timer which searches for the window periodically and if it exists fills it and simulates the user pressing OK.  There are a couple of lines commented out these are other methods I have tried with no success:

```
    Dim filePath As String = String.Empty
    Dim MessageSender As Long = Nothing
    Dim printToFileWindowHandle As Long = Nothing
    Dim textboxHandle As Long = Nothing
    Dim okButtonHandle As Long = Nothing

    printToFileWindowHandle = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Print to File")
    If printToFileWindowHandle <> 0 Then
        filePath = "C:\test.prn"
        MessageSender = SendDlgItemMessage(printToFileWindowHandle, 201, WM_SETTEXT, 0, filePath)
        MessageSender = SendMessage(printToFileWindowHandle, WM_SHOWWINDOW, 0, 0)
        'okButtonHandle = GetDlgItem(printToFileWindowHandle, IDOK)
        okButtonHandle = FindWindowEx(printToFileWindowHandle, 0, "Button", "OK")
        'textboxHandle = FindWindowEx(printToFileWindowHandle, 0, "Edit", vbNullString)
        'MessageSender = SendMessage(textboxHandle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, filePath)
        MessageSender = SendMessage(okButtonHandle, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
        Application.DoEvents()
    End if
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can setup adobe to use a different port. For example, you can create an Adobe port to "C:\TEMP\PDFOUTPUT\" and set your Adobe printer to use it. There are also settings in the Adobe printer to control where the default location is - set this to your directory/port - and whether to overwrite/prompt user for filenames - turn this off so it just writes into the folder.

One thing we have done is leave the Adobe printer alone and setup a new local printer using the driver "Adobe PDF Converter" which gives another PDF printer. This one we will setup to go to specific folders with no user interaction. We name the printer accodingly so tha the user knows this printer will print to a location. for example "Report Printer" vs "Adobe PDF 2"